# Problema ao importar novas bibliotecas ao Java

Tags: java

Estou tentando criar um aplicativo que possa interagir com um dispositivo MIDI, para isso estou usando a biblioteca JMusic, porém depois de colocar o arquivo .jar no meu Workspace e te-lo adicionado ao projeto, os pacotes daquela biblioteca parecem não existir, caso eu não tenha sido específico no meu problema, eis aqui um Print da minha tela:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

será que é problema com o .jar? Estou vendo um tutoriais de um cara, e eu baixei no mesmo site que ele...

Comment: A exclamação vermelha sobre o ícone da pasta do seu projeto indica que você tem um problema no seu Build Path. Clique na aba Problems que ele dará mais detalhes, edite sua pergunta e adicione as informações que essa aba informa.

Answer (score 1):

Conheço três possíveis soluções para o problema:

No Eclipse, clique com o botão direito sobre a pasta do seu projeto e siga o caminho: `Build Path > Configure Build Path`. Na aba `Libraries` pressione o botão `Add External JARs` e selecione o *.jar da `JMusic`.

A segunda opção te ajudaria a organizar melhor as dependências. Neste caso você criaria uma pasta `lib` dentro do seu projeto e copiaria o *.jar da `JMusic` pra lá. Após isso você clica com o botão direito no JAR e segue o caminho: `Build Path > Add To Build Path`.

Uma solução mais elegante entretanto, é criar um projeto [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/) e no arquivo de configuração definir a JMusic como dependência. Durante o primeiro build o Gradle se encarregará de baixar a biblioteca e adicioná-la ao buildpath automaticamente.